# Как исправить ошибку IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.x

Код:

```
#!/bin/python

import sys

try:
    sys.argv[1]
except:
    print "Usage: python killpid.py pids.txt"
    sys.exit()

kill_lis = open(sys.argv[1],"r").read()

b = kill_lis.split("\n")
a = []
c = []
for i in  range(len(b)-1):
    c.append(b[i].split(" "))
    h = c[i][0]+c[i][1] 
    lists = h.split(":")
    spl = lists[1].replace("?","")
    a.append(spl.replace("pts/0",""))

for i in range(len(a)):
    result = a[i]+"\x0a"
print " ".join(a)
```

Ошибка возникает на 20 строке, интерпретатор ругается на

```
spl = lists[1].replace("?","")
```

что бы получить файл pids.txt

```
ps -A | grep ping >> pids.txt
```

Comment: На какой строке возникает ошибка?

Comment: может у вас пустой массив kill_lis?

Comment: @insolor Где я указал метку на python3

Comment: В самом вопросе, когда создавали его: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpBPB.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps -A | grep ping >> pids.txt` дает строки вида `22538 pts/1    00:00:00 ping`.

Смотрим что вы делаете:

```
b = kill_lis.split("\n")  # разбиение на отдельные строки

c.append(b[i].split(" "))  # разбиение по пробелам, добавление в список
# В результате в список добавляется подсписок вида ['22538', 'pts/1', '', '', '', '00:00:00', 'ping']
# Мне кажется, удобнее разбивать без указания разделителя, тогда будет разбиваться по группе пробелов: ['22538', 'pts/1', '00:00:00', 'ping']

h = c[i][0]+c[i][1]
# Склеиваете первый и второй элементы подсписка вместе, получается '22538pts/1'

lists = h.split(":")
# разбиваете полученную выше строку по двоеточию - т.к. двоеточий там нет,
# то получается список из одного элемента ['22538pts/1']

spl = lists[1].replace("?","") 
# пытаетесь взять второй элемент из полученного выше списка -
# вылетает ошибка IndexError: list index out of range
```

Кроме исправления этой проблемы, нужно еще добавить обработку пустых строк: т.к. под linux текстовый файл всегда заканчивается на `\n`, то при разбиении по этому символу в конце гарантированно получится пустая строка.

Вообще, в таких ситуациях полезно на каждом этапе выводить промежуточный результат (или еще лучше - запускать под отладчиком).

Comment: Или вместо split использовать str.splitlines -- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines

Comment: @gil9red, вообще проще прямо по файловому объекту итерироваться - я всегда только так и делаю.

Comment: Согласен, так наиболее проще :)